# Android SQLite Query syntax error CREATE_TABLE

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I am not sure what is wrong with this query syntax but it just never works. My programming grabs all the correct info but fails at this point.

```
    public String CREATE_QUERY = "CREATE_TABLE "+ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.TABLE_NAME+"("+ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.RECEIPT_ID+" STRING,"+ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.RECEIPT_FILE+" STRING,"+ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.RECEIPT_URI+" STRING);";
```

Here is the error that it gives:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.section32point5.digiceit/com.example.section32point5.digiceit.CameraActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "CREATE_TABLE": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE_TABLE receipts_table(receipt_ID STRING,receipt_FILE STRING,receipt_IMAGE STRING);
```

So to me, it finds the right names but cannot run it. Im guessing ive missed a colon or something.

Thanks in advance

EDIT: I just realised and don't understand why the first comment says:

```
D/Database operations: Table created
```

Then it says:

```
E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "CREATETABLE": syntax error
```

Comment: Get rid of the underscore between `CREATE` and `TABLE`.

Comment: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html

Comment: Unfortunatly that didnt work. Same error.

Comment: Because now you've made [another error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21881992/when-is-sqliteopenhelper-oncreate-onupgrade-run).

Comment: I don't understand. I just edited my post with the latest ive found. SQLite is not forgiving is it. One small space missed and your doomed.

Comment: Sorry, my initial comment was ambiguous. `CREATE` and `TABLE` are two separate words. You do need a space between them.

Comment: Excellent thank you very much. The table's are now created and the data inputs each time. Thanks Mike M.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
public String CREATE_QUERY = " CREATE_TABLE " + ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.TABLE_NAME + " ( " + ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.RECEIPT_ID + " STRING, " + ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.RECEIPT_FILE + " STRING, " +ReceiptsTable.TableInformation.RECEIPT_URI + " STRING); ";
```

Comment: This is not correct. Please refer to the comments on the question.